# Which is a better singleton implementation?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I was looking at these two implementations of the Singleton Pattern:

```
 Class Customer {

int x;
static int count = 0;

private Customer()
{
    x = 1;
}

public static Customer GetCustomer()
{
    if(count==0)
    {
        count++;
        return new Customer();
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Implementation 1 in which the constructor is not called if the class is already instantiated once. OR

```
 Class Customer{

int x;
static int count = 0;
public Customer()
{
    if(count == 0)
    {
        x = 1;
        count++;
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Implementation 2 in which the constructor is called irrespective of weather the class is already instantiated once or not. I watched a video lecture online that says Implementation 2 is not preferred as it allocates memory for the constructor although the object is not instantiated for the second time. I am aware Java has automatic Garbage Collection, but just wanted to know if what I watched in the video lecture is relevant.

Comment: Where did you find these implementations of a "singleton pattern"? If you found them in a book, I hope you kept your receipt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some that would say that *no* implementation of a singleton is the correct one, but I'm not quite in that camp.

People often tend to use them badly (as a God object, for example) but they still have their place (in my *opinion,* which has little to do with this answer).

For the purposes of this answer, I'm going to assume you've made the right decision in needing a singleton, but I do urge you to read up on its potential problems - there may well be a better way to achieve your ends.

---

Having said that, I'm not sure if your code samples are correct anyway. A singleton is supposed to return one and only one instance, creating one if necessary, giving you the previously created one if not.

I fail to see how your first code sample honors that contract. It'll give you a new one the first time it's called, then it will give you *nothing* after that.

And your second code sample doesn't seem to prevent multiple objects *at all.*

So I'd be thinking *very* carefully about whether you want to continue watching that video, if this is the quality of the education they deliver.

---

In any case, I prefer the one that only constructs once, since you're only supposed to have one object of that class. In other words, a static `getMe()` call that is *properly* synchronised to prevent race conditions allowing creation of more than one `Me` object, and that creates a new object the first time, returning that *same* object on subsequent calls.

In pseudo-code, that would be something like:

```
class Me {
    private Me() {};

    private static Me *loner = NULL;

    public static synchronised Me *getMe() {
        if loner == NULL
            loner = new Me();
        return loner;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing a correct singleton is not that easy. You need to take care of race conditions and to defend against reflection attacks. For example a private constructor might be invoked via reflection to create one more instance of an object. The easiest and safest singleton implementation in java is done with an enum:

```
enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;
}
```

That's because enum constants are spedified by JLS to be singletons (section 8.9 of JLS):

> An enum type has no instances other than those defined by its enum constants.